# PHP PDO escape question mark so it doesn't think it is a placeholder

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('path/to/page/?id=', id) AS link FROM users WHERE name = ?
```

I am using PDO to prepare this statement and I am getting the error

```
Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

because it thinks the question mark in the CONCAT string is a placeholder.

Is there any way to escape the question mark so PDO knows that it is not a placeholder?

**Please no comments about other ways to get the link. I am changing old code that goes into an old templating engine so it would be A LOT less work to find a way to escape the question mark than to not put a question mark in the query.**

Comment: As far as I can tell PDO is clever enough to understand there can be no placeholders within strings. Could you perhaps paste the entire PHP command?

Comment: Sorry forgot the 'FROM users'

Comment: Please show us more code, it's hard to say for certain why it's thinking that.

Comment: My mistake PDO was correct my query actually looked like this: ... name = '?'. So PDO didn't think I had any placeholders in the query. I am surprised that I was not able to find in the PDO documentation how to escape a question mark with '?'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDO is not confused by the question mark inside the quotes. I just test this with PHP 5.5.15.

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT('path/to/page/?id=', id) AS link FROM foo WHERE name = ?;";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(1, 'name');
$stmt->execute();
print_r($stmt->fetchAll());
```

It works fine, with no error about a wrong number of parameters. Your error is caused by the way you're binding parameters, not by the SQL syntax.

I suspect you haven't shown us the whole SQL query, because WHERE without FROM is a syntax error anyway. So you must have additional parameter placeholders that you haven't shown us. It would also be helpful if you show us the way you're binding parameters (or passing parameters to execute()).

Comment: I see you're part of the Code Detectives Network ;) +1 - I thought the same thing, yet I wanted to see OP's *actual* code before submitting an answer; *good work Bill*.

Comment: I marked this the answer because you are correct. This is one of those "u dumby" mistakes. my query actually looked like this: SELECT CONCAT('path/to/page/?id=', id) AS link FROM users WHERE name = '?' so PDO didn't think there were any placeholders

Comment: @UziTech Then, why did you post your question as not being what you were actually using in the first place? You would have gotten a faster answer. (wink)

Comment: @Fred because there is sensitive information in the actuall query

Comment: @UziTech I understand and respect that. *However*, you posted `WHERE name = ?` but said you were actually using `WHERE name = '?'` with quotes around the question mark; *that's why*. (wink) - That is what I meant by "actual". It just leaves the guesswork out of things. But Bill did find the solution and that's good, *cheers*

Answer (score 4):

This is a very old question, but the escaping of question marks [have landed into PHP 7.4](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/pdo_escape_placeholders).

A question mark is escaped by adding a second... question mark.

In your query, you could add this:

```php
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT('path/to/page/??id=', id) AS link FROM users WHERE name = ?";
```

For usage with json or jsonb operator in postgresql:

```php
$sql = "SELECT '["a", "b", "c"]'::jsonb ?? 'a'";
```

Comment: Nice answer. How do you do this in version < PHP7.4?